# String to Integer Conversion in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, editbox

I am just a beginner to MFC platform. I am just trying a simple pgm. Getting 2 numbers in 2 edit boxes and displaying the sum in the third edit box when a button is clicked.

This is my code:

```
void CMineDlg::OnEnChangeNumber1()
{
   CString strNum1,strNum2;
   m_Number1.GetWindowText(strNum1,10);   //m_NUmber1 is variable to 1st edit box.
   m_Number2.GetWindowText(strNum2,10);   //m_Number2 is variable to 2nd edit box.
} 

void CMineDlg::OnBnClickedSum()
{
   m_Result=m_Number1+m_Number2;
}
```

I know I have to convert the strings to integer. But I have no idea how to do it. Pls Help.

Comment: If there s some thread related to this pls post it her. I didnt find it. Pls help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Class Wizard to add variables of integer type and associate them with edit boxes. Then, in `OnEnChangeNumber1` event handler (or in `OnBnClickedSum`), you simply call `UpdateData(TRUE);` which causes those variables to update their values. After that, you can sum those integer variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I have created integer variables for edit boxes and associated them with the edit boxes. In Button Event handler I have added the two numbers. There is no error in it. But when it is executed the first edit box is displaying 0 and the second is displaying -858993460 and the result edit box is showing -858993460 even without the button is clicked. I want to get user input using GetWindowText. So the input will be in string type. Also pls help in string to integer conversion.

Comment: As for strange negative values, you should initialize your integer variables **before** showing the dialog. You can do this in the constructor or in the `OnInitDialog` method. 
Again, you *don't need* to convert strings to integers and vise versa. MFC will do it for you. When you call `UpdateData(TRUE)`, MFC internally takes string values from text boxes via `GetWindowsText` and converts them to appropriate types of your associated variables. When you call `UpdateData(FALSE)`, MFC converts your associated variables to strings and populates text boxes.

Comment: Of course. If `m_Result` is associated with text box, you should call `UpdateData(FALSE)` to propagate the result into text box.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
CString strNum = _T("11");  //CString variable
int num;                //Integer Variable
_stscanf(strNum, _T("%d"), &num);   //Conversion
```

Or

```
num = atoi((char*)(LPCTSTR)strNum);
```

Comment: This is not UNICODE compliant

Answer (score -1):

The correct UNICODE compliant way of doing this:

```
CString str = _T("10");
int nVal = _ttoi(str);
__int64 = _ttoi64(str);
```